# How to make an image fill the background of a div? (using img tag in the div itself)

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, css-selectors

This seems like a simple problem but I'm having a bit of trouble finding a solution. I have cards on my page and I simply want the image (in the img tag which is inside the div) to fill the background of the div. The way the page is set up I want the img tag inside the div to take up the whole background. I know I can use background img in the css file. but I want each image to be different and have them fit their divs. Trying to figure out how to style them to do this. This is what it looks like, hopefully my question is clear..

Here is the code for the card and image:

```
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552465011" alt="">
                    <div class="card-description">
                        <h5>Title of Post</h5>
                        <img src="" alt="text">
                        <p> Some text here.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.container .card{
    background: lightgreen;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width: 285px;
    height: 145px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 0%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have two `<img>` tags in your markup. Which one do you want to fill the whole of `.card`?

Comment: yes, the first img sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there

By using `max-width: 100%;` `max-height: 100%`

You are limiting your image to either take full width or height of the container.

Simply remove the `max` and just use `width: 100%` `height: 100%`

Then `object-fit` property will show it's effect.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `<img>` tags in your markup. I assumed you want the first `<img>` tag to fill the containing `<div>`.

You can use [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/object-fit). There are other values available with `object-fit` but `cover` stretches the image so it covers the container, but without changing the aspect ratio of your image.

You can then limit the `img` to be 100% of the width and height of the container.

Note that since this may truncate part of your image if the image's aspect ratio is not the same as the container, you can also use [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) to adjust the alignment of the image with the container.

See these examples below.

```css
h5 {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 285px;
  height: 145px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.card-image {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: bottom;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-description {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="http://cdn.wallpapername.com/1920x1080/20190806/5d498ca7ac412.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="card-description">
      <h5>Title of Post</h5>
      <p> Some text here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="https://static.fanpage.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/22/2020/07/iStock-464788862.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="card-description">
      <h5>Title of Post</h5>
      <p> Some text here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-image" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/three-lovely-puffy-tit-sitting-on-a-branch-in-winter-sunny-park-picture-id865636134?k=6&m=865636134&s=612x612&w=0&h=dAqcmx8ETyzUOpk_g5-4uWLZeTDdt-6Qe9tENCAcj20=" alt="">
    <div class="card-description">
      <h5>Title of Post</h5>
      <p> Some text here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is somehow right but I have revamped your code. Check this.

```
   img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            object-fit: cover;
            object-position: center;
        }

        .container .card {
            background: lightgreen;
            color: black;
            width: 285px;
            height: 145px;
            margin: 15px;
            padding: 0%;
            border: 2px solid black;
            position: relative;
        }

        .card-description {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            display: flex;
            align-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .card-heading, .card-content{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .card-description h5,
        .card-description p {
            margin: 0;
            color: #fff;
        }
 <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1651592753269-7d661e4a9899?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
                alt="">
            <div class="card-description">
                <div class="card-heading">
                    <h5>Title of Post</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <p> Some text here.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
    display:block,
    width:100%,
    background-size:cover,
    background-position:center center
  }

or

.card img {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%
   }
```